# altering makefile dependencies so intermediate files are not created

Tags: makefile

Sorry if this is a dup, but I couldn't seem to find it anywhere.

I'm working on making a makefile that creates a number of intermediate files, many of which are very large. I had set up the makefile so I would delete these intermediate files as I go along, but not it seems like it's coming back to bite me.

for example, if file10 is dependent on file9 only, I would make the depedency like:

```
file10 : file9
file9 : file8
etc...
```

if I was at the step of creating `file10`, I would have deleted everything except file9. However, if I delete all files, and then perform the command:

```
make file10
```

all the intermediate files are being created... I've tried marking the filenames as both `.INTERMEDIATE : file8 file7 ... etc`, and `.SECONDARY : ...`, but that doesn't seem to change the behavior in any way.

I realize this is probably a normally good feature of make, but I'm wondering if I can disable it in any way?

Thanks!

EDIT: here is the complete makefile. This may be a bit sloppy for some, I am very new to makefiles. One thing to note, the 'fastq-dump' functions will give files with a *_1.fastq and (in some cases) also as *_2.fastq. That's why the dependencies are weird at the beginning

```
## all          : execute all functions in this makefile (currently not being implemented)
all:
## run_bqsr     : runs bqsr on data using SNPs identified using SAMTOOLS mpileup command
.PHONY : run_bqsr
run_bqsr : $(BAMFILE)_recal_data.grp
         module load R_3.2.2 && java -jar /opt/gatk/3.3-0/GenomeAnalysisTK.jar -T BaseRecalibrator -nct 8 -R $(REF_GENOME_PATH) -I $(BAMFILE)_realigned_reads.bam -BQSR $(BAMFILE)_recal_data.grp -o $(BAMFILE)_post_recal_data.grp -plots $(BAMFILE)_after_recal.pdf
%_recal_data.grp : %_mpileup.bcf
        module load module load R_3.2.2 && java -jar /opt/gatk/3.3-0/GenomeAnalysisTK.jar -T BaseRecalibrator -nct 8 -R $(REF_GENOME_PATH) -I $*_realigned_reads.bam -knownSites $*_mpileup.bcf -o $*_recal_data.grp -plots $*_before_recal.pdf
# create a reference of 'known' SNPs using samtools mpileup. use the -B option to increase sensitivity (important not to include false negatives in analysis because it will mess up the process of adjusting base scores
%_mpileup.bcf : %_realigned_reads.bam
        module load samtools_1.2 && samtools mpileup -C50 --BCF -B -f $(REF_GENOME_PATH) $*_realigned_reads.bam -o $*_mpileup.bcf

## realign_indels       : realign raw sequencing reads around indels using GATK's RealignerTargetCreator and IndelRealiner
.PHONY : realign_indels
realign_indels : $(BAMFILE)_realigned_reads.bam
%_realigned_reads.bam : %_target_intervals.list
        java -jar /opt/gatk/3.3-0/GenomeAnalysisTK.jar -T IndelRealigner -R $(REF_GENOME_PATH) -I $(BAMFILE)_dedup_reads.bam -targetIntervals $*_target_intervals.list -o $*_realigned_reads.bam && rm $(BAMFILE)_dedup_reads.ba* $(BAMFILE)_target_intervals.list

%_target_intervals.list : $(BAMFILE)_dedup_reads.bam
        java -jar /opt/gatk/3.3-0/GenomeAnalysisTK.jar -T RealignerTargetCreator -nt 8 -R $(REF_GENOME_PATH) -I $(BAMFILE)_dedup_reads.bam -o $*_target_intervals.list

## remove_dups  : remove duplicate reads from SAMfiles, sort, and convert to a single merged BAM file
.PHONY : remove_dups
remove_dups : $(BAMFILE)_dedup_reads.bam
$(BAMFILE)_dedup_reads.bam : $(SAMFILES)
        mkdir -p $(BAMFILE_DIR)/metrics; java -jar /opt/picard/1.72/MarkDuplicates.jar $(addprefix I=, $(SAMFILES)) OUTPUT=$(BAMFILE)_dedup_reads.bam M=$(BAMFILE_DIR)/metrics/$(QUERY_INPUT).metrics && java -jar /opt/picard/1.72/BuildBamIndex.jar I=$(BAMFILE)_dedup_reads.bam && rm -r $(SAMFILE_TEMPDIR)/* $(FASTQ_DIR)/*
#mark samfiles and fastq files as secondary:
.INTERMEDIATE : $(SAMFILE_TEMPDIR)/* $(FASTQ_DIR)/*
## map_fastqs   : map fastq files to appropriate genome
.PHONY : map_fastqs
map_fastqs : $(SAMFILES)
%_sorted.sam : $(FASTQs)
        module load bwa_0.7.13; mkdir -p $(dir $*) ; if echo $(PAIRED) | grep $(notdir $*); then bwa mem -M -R '@RG\tID:$(notdir $*)$(RG)' $(REF_GENOME_PATH) $(FASTQ_DIR)/$(notdir $*)_1.fastq $(FASTQ_DIR)/$(notdir $*)_2.fastq > $*.sam ; else bwa mem -M -R '@RG\tID:$(notdir $*)$(RG)' $(REF_GENOME_PATH) $(FASTQ_DIR)/$(notdir $*)_1.fastq > $*.sam; fi && java -jar /opt/picard/1.72/SortSam.jar I=$*.sam O=$*_sorted.sam SORT_ORDER=coordinate 

## print_fastqs : print full path fastq files to be written
.PHONY : print_fastqs
print_fastqs :
        @echo $(addprefix ../FASTQ/$(QUERY_INPUT)/,$(ALL_FASTQs))
## get_fastqs   : get all fastq files for particular query:
.PHONY : get_fastqs
get_fastqs : $(ALL_FASTQs)
%_2.fastq : %_1.fastq
        $(MARK_READS_EXE) $*_1.fastq && $(MARK_READS_EXE) $*_2.fastq
%_1.fastq :
        mkdir -p $(dir $*); cd $(dir $*); $(FASTQDUMP_EXE) --split-files -F -I -X 10000 $(notdir $*)
#$(ALL_FASTQs) : $(FASTQs)
#       echo $* $<
## give_org     : print organism of this biosample
.PHONY : give_org
give_org :
        @echo $(ORGANISM)

## print_SRRs   : print the SRR files that will be downloaded
.PHONY : print_SRRs
print_SRRs :
        @printf '\nPAIRED = $(PAIRED)\nUNPAIRED = $(UNPAIRED)\n'

## clean                : clean up temporary files
.PHONY : clean
clean :
        rm $(FASTQ_DIR)/SRR* $(SAMFILE_TEMPDIR)/*.sam $(BAMFILE_DIR)/$(QUERY_INPUT)*

## help         : print help statement
.PHONY : help
help : makefile
        @sed -n 's/^##//p' $<
```

Comment: Show a complete example, is there ultimately a physical, permanent file that is a prerequisite of `file1`? Because if not then it's no surprise that make recreates everything: if `file1` doesn't exist then it needs to be remade, which means `file2` needs to be remade, which means etc. etc. I think your question about intermediate files may be a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've correctly understood how your question relates to your makefile, `%_1.fastq :` doesn't have any prerequisites, which means make will **always** remake any target that matches this pattern if it doesn't exist.

If it has any prerequisites then add them, if not then these files aren't intermediate files at all and you need to tell make as much by making them explicit targets with something like

```
$(filter %_1.fastq,$(ALL_FASTQs)):
    # Recipe
```

You could do the same with `.PRECIOUS: %_1.fastq` although this has the additional effect of leaving the files when the recipe fails, which is probably not something you want.